# Errors when trying to call a method

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been looking around online, and I am still unsure of how to call a method in my child class. I am trying to call the pay() method in Executive, and when I type in the following code into my if statement, I keep getting an error.

```
staff[3].awardBonus(bonus);
```

I keep getting an error with this method. I'm not sure how to call that method... Thanks for any help!`import java.util.Scanner;

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        StaffMember[] staff = new StaffMember[4];
        String internName = "Susan 2";
        String empName = "Tyler O.";
        String hrName = "Becky R.";
        String execName = "Daniel H.";
        String address = "Brighton";
        String phone = "420 - 0000";
        String SSN = "12345789";
        double rate = 1000;

        staff [0] = new Intern(internName, address, phone);
        staff [1] = new Employee(empName, address, phone, SSN, rate);
        staff [2] = new HourlyEmployee(hrName, address, phone, SSN, rate);
        staff [3] = new Executive(execName, address, phone, SSN, rate);


        for (StaffMember staffPrint : staff)
        {
            System.out.println (staffPrint.toString() + "\n");    
        }

        System.out.println("If you would like to give an executive a bonus, press 1. \nIf you would like to increase the hours of an hourly employee, press 2.");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if(input == 1)
        {
            double bonus = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter the bonus for your employee: ");
            bonus = scan.nextDouble(); 

        }
 }
```

Here is the Executive class, Employee class and the StaffMember class

```
public class Executive extends Employee
{
    public Executive(String name, String address, String phone, String SSN, double rate)
    {
        super(name, address, phone, SSN, rate);
    }

    public double pay()
    {
        double money = super.pay();
        return money;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String employee = super.toString();
        return employee;
    }

    public void awardBonus(double execBonus)
    {
        rate += execBonus;
    }
}
```

Employee

```
    public class Employee extends StaffMember
{
    String SSN;
    double rate;

    public Employee(String name, String address, String phone, String SSN, double rate)
    {
        super(name, address, phone);
        this.SSN = SSN;
        this.rate = rate;  
    }

    public double pay()
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String employee = "";        
        employee = ("Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nPhone Number: " + phone + "\nSocial Security Number: " + SSN + "\nPay: " + pay());        
        return employee;
    }
}
```

StaffMember

```
public abstract class StaffMember
{
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;

    public StaffMember(String name, String address, String phone)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String employee = "";        
        employee = ("Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nPhone Number: " + phone);        
        return employee;
    }

    public abstract double pay();
}
```

Comment: And what does the error say?

Comment: The error is saying "cannot find symbol - method awardBonus(double)"

Comment: You need to read up on how inheritance and polymorphism works. You have a `StaffMember[]`, AFAICS there is no `awardBonus` method on `StaffMember`; therefore you cannot call it. You may say, "but I put an `Executive` at element `3` and I'm calling `awardBonus` on that - if this were allowed to compile and I did `staff[3] = new FiredStaffMember` somewhere else in the code, what would happen then?

Answer (score 1):

`staff` is a `StaffMember` array. When you reference any item from it (as you do it `staff[3]`), you get a `StaffMember`.

`StaffMember` does not have a method `awardBonus()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to call an undefined method on your `StaffMember` object. In fact the method `awardBonus()` was not defined in your `StaffMember` class.

And in the code `staff[3].awardBonus(bonus)` you were trying to call `awardBonus()` on `staff[3]` which is a `StaffMember` instance.

Answer (score 1):

By providing an `awardBonus` for all StaffMembers, you can call it on a StaffMember. For instance:

```
public abstract class StaffMember
{
    public void awardBonus(double bonus) {
        if (bonus > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Only executives receive a bonus");
        }
    }
...

public class Executive extends StaffMember
{
    @Override
    public void awardBonus(double bonus) {
```

P.S. be careful to inform the company on this.

Comment: I think it would be better, if `StaffMember` contains an `abstract` `awardBonus` method, so every subtype handles the bonus itself.

Comment: @ThomasBöhm But then an executive related function must be implemented everywhere, instead of a default none-behaviour. But yes, one should consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
// Check if staff[3] is really an Executive
if(staff[3] instanceof Executive) {
    // Cast staff[3] to an Executive
    Executive executive = ((Executive)staff[3]);
    // Now you can call awardBonus
    executive.awardBonus(bonus);
}
```

Because `staff` is an StaffMember-array which doesn't contains the methode `awardBonus`.
You know that `staff[3]` is an `Executive`, but your program doesn't. Therefore you have to check if `staff[3]` is an instanceof Executive so you can safely cast it to an `Executive` with `Executive executive = (Executive)staff[3]`.